# Hex code validation not working in laravel

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, rules

I want to validate a color input field. I want to check whether input value is hex color or not using regex pattern.

```
'icon_color' => 'required|regex:^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$',
```

This is the rule I've made but it gives following error.

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Could someone tell what I am doing wrong. Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When using the `regex` / `not_regex` patterns, it may be necessary to
>   specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially
>   if the regular expression contains a pipe character. See the
>   [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex).

So, try:

```
'icon_color' => ['required', 'regex:/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/']
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This: `icon_color' => 'required|regex:^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$'`, needs to become this: `'icon_color' => 'required|regex:/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/'`.

The regular expression itself needs to be surrounded by backslashes (`/`), similar to Javascript's way of treating strings as regular expressions.

Comment: Still same error